# How to publish xml to JMS queue

Tags: javascript, jms, activemq-classic

How to publish xml to ActiveMQ ? I tried publishing it as text but i want to get it as xml back after subscription, therefore it's not preferable option.

```
String myxml = ... 
session.createTextMessage(myXml);
```

Comment: So is there a problem taking the text response you get from the queue and treating it as XML? parsing it, etc?

Comment: I'm using Mule ESB at other end and just wanted to avoid additional step for parsing to xml. It would have been straight forward for me if i could publish as xml object

Comment: Even if it returned 'XML', you would have to parse the xml you got back,right?  It doesn't sound like a lot of extra work.